# Facing problem in storing User data in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, angular5

I am working on a Angular based application , I want to store data of all the fields of the form , without using service because for that I need to require a server side Language like php and .net which I don't know.

so can I store form data using other way from  firebase  or something else that you suggest ..?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could set up a Firebase Environment and use its real-time database. Firebase is a Backend as a Service (BaaS), so it’s exactly what you need.